# Jump Point Search: mix between Normal and Orthogonal

Tags: algorithm, path, artificial-intelligence, path-finding

## Context

I am using JPS for a game so that the AI can chase something. The problem is that while chasing, I can't afford them to diagonally jump though blocked paths.

## Explanation

I took 2 screenshots to compare their behaviours (using [this](http://qiao.github.io/PathFinding.js/visual/) website):

*JPS* vs. *Orthogonal JPS*:

[image] 
[image]

## Goal

By taking both, I want it to search like this (going around borders but also diagonally searching).

*Mixed*:

[image]

## Question

**(1)** Does Orthogonal expand in 4 directions while Normal Jump Point Seach expands in 8 directions?

If so, **(2)** would make Orthogonal expand to 8 directions to be enough?

Thanks.

Comment: Looking from the second picture it's not only wether it only expands in 4 directions, it creates jump points or forced neighbors in places regular JPS would not. The blue square 6 places to the right and 2 down from the green square in the second picture would not usually be a forced neighbor but instead the node below it. But it isnt because they dont look diagonally. This is what you will ahve to consider as well. And yes I believe the answer to question (1) is that it expands in 4 directions.

Answer (score 0):

Might you had use "Don't cross corners" Options.

As well try trace algorithm with chebyshev options.

[image]